# How do I set up an express route where parameters have multiple slashes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to set up an endpoint like below:

```
http://localhost:5000/guardian/lifeandstyle/2020/apr/26/bring-your-skin-to-life-with-a-hint-of-bronzer
```

I currently set up my endpoint like this:

```
router.get('/guardian/:articleId', (req, res) => {

const id = req.params.articleId;
console.log(id);

axios.get('https://content.guardianapis.com/'+ id +'?api-key=' + guardianapi + '&show-blocks=all')
    .then(function (response) {
        res.send(response.data);
    });
});
```

But I'm getting a 404 error once I enter the endpoint in my browser

Comment: what is your articleId in above endpoint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) which has an example:

> ```
> app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', function (req, res) {
>   res.send(req.params)
> })
> ```

You just put multiple `/` in the route and multiple names starting with a `:`.